# Unable to find Mongo class in Connection.php Symfony 2

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-mongodb

This is quite an often occurring error, but since I tried a lot of stuff to fix it, I'm kind of getting out of the ideas.

I have a symfony 2 with mongo DB. I have set up my composer.json file to download doctrine-mongo and doctrine-mongo-bundle,

```
"doctrine/mongodb-odm": "1.0.*@beta",
"doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*@beta",
```

In order to download this 2 modules, I needed to have mongo extension installed into PHP. I have both of them, mongo and mongodb, installed via brew

```
brew install php56-mongo
brew install php56-mongodb
```

I believe I have mongo extensions allowed as well, since when I write

```
php -m
```

I get this results

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mhash
mongo
mongodb
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
odbc
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
PDO_ODBC
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib
```

and you can see mongo there.

Also php -i returns info that mongo is enabled.

But when I'm trying to hit app_dev.php file in my project, I still get this:

> ClassNotFoundException in Connection.php line 284: Attempted to load
>   class "Mongo" from the global namespace. Did you forget a "use"
>   statement?

I'm using a Mac OS X and have chmod 777 on

```
app/logs
app/cache 
web/
```

recursively.

Do you have any idea what can trigger this ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Cli and fpm/apache doesn't use the same configuration, which means your `php -m` may be not accurate.

What you can do is call http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php inside your php entry point file on your server and make sure its loaded. Restarting the processes can help as well.